Finding $A+B+C$ in $\cos^4(x)=A+B\cos(2x)+C\cos(4x)$?

Given $\cos^4(x)=A+B\cos(2x)+C\cos(4x)$, Find $A+B+C$.

I'm having trouble trying to find this sum $A+B+C$, here is my attempt so far:
I know that $\cos(4x)=8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x)+1$ and $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$.
Substituting those values into the equation gives a new relation,
$$\cos^4(x)=A+B+C-2B\sin^2(x)+(8C-1)\cos^4(x)-8C\cos^2(x)$$
Then I used the identity $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$, letting $P=A+B+C$, and $D=\cos^2(x)$ which turns the above equation into a quadratic:
$$(8C-1)\cos^4(x)+2(B-4C)\cos^2(x)+P-2B=0$$
From here I assume $D_1$ and $D_2$ as roots, therefore by Vieta's formulas I have arrived at, $$D_{1}+D_{2}-D_{1}D_{2}=\frac{8C-P}{8C-1}$$
I'm not so sure what to do from here, what should I do now?

it is also true that $\cos 2x = 2 \cos^2 x - 1 $

There's no need to solve for $A, B, C$ individually---just evaluate at $x = 0$.

@TravisWillse I see, thanks!

There is no reason to use Vieta’s Formulas, I believe. Take the equation you found: $$(8C-1)\cos^4(x)+2(B-4C)\cos^2(x)+A-B+C
=0$$
This must be true for all values of $x$. So, you can essentially treat this as a polynomial in terms of $\cos x$. A polynomial that is zero for all values in $[-1, 1]$ is zero for all values. So, the polynomial must be the zero polynomial.
So, the coefficient of $\cos^4(x)$, the coefficient of $\cos^2 x$, and the constant coefficient must all be zero. This give you three linear equations and three variables. This seems like a homework problem, so I’ll leave it to you to solve for $A + B + C$.

So I could just plug in $x=0$ to get $A+B+C=1$?

Oh, oops…. that made me feel really dumb. Yeah, that would be much easier and probably the intended solution.

Expand $\cos^4(x)$ using the double angle formula $\cos^2(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(2\theta) + 1)$:
\begin{align*}
\cos^4(x) &= (\cos^2(x))^2,\\
&= \left(\frac12(\cos(2x)+1)\right)^2,\\
&= \frac14(\cos^2(2x)+2\cos(2x)+1),\\
&= \frac14\left(\frac12(\cos(4x)+1)+2\cos(2x)+1\right),\\
&= \frac18(\cos(4x)+1)+\frac12\cos(2x)+\frac14,\\
&= \frac18\cos(4x)+\frac12\cos(2x)+\frac38.
\end{align*}
Then, you see that $A=\frac38$, $B=\frac12$, $C=\frac18$, so their sum is $A+B+C=1$.

$\cos^4 x = A + B\cos 2x + C\cos 4x\\
\cos 4x = 8\cos^4 x - 8\cos^2x + 1\\
\cos 2x = 2\cos^2 x - 1\\
u = \cos^2 x\\
u^2 = A+ 2Bu - B + 8Cu^2 - 8Cu + C\\
u^2 = (A-B+C)+ (2B-8C)u + 8Cu^2$
Setting the $u^2$ terms the $u$ terms and the constant terms on the LHS and RHS equal to one another suggests a system of linear equations.
$8C = 1\\
2B-8C = 0\\
A-B+C = 0$
Solving this system:
$C = \frac 18\\
B = \frac 12\\
A = \frac 38$
Alternative.
Plug $x = 0, \frac {\pi}{4}, \frac {\pi}{2}$ into the original equation.
$1 = A + B + C\\
\frac 14 = A - C\\
0 = A - B + C$
Alternative II
$\pmatrix {1&-1&1\\0&2&-8\\0&0&8}\pmatrix {A\\B\cos 2x\\C \cos 4x} = \pmatrix {P\\Q\cos^2x\\ R\cos^4x}$
Multiplying both on the right by $\pmatrix {1&-1&1\\0&2&-8\\0&0&8}^{-1}$ changes the basis in the other direction.
$\pmatrix {A\\B\cos 2x\\C \cos 4x} = \pmatrix {1&\frac 12 &\frac 38\\0&\frac 12&\frac 12\\0&0&\frac 18} \pmatrix {P\\Q\cos^2x\\ R\cos^4x}$
And for this particular problem set $P = 0, Q = 0, R = 1$
Alternative III (Sorry, new ideas poping up)
$\cos x = \frac {e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}\\
\cos^4 x = \frac {(e^{ix} + e^{-ix})^4}{16}\\
\frac {e^{4ix} + 4e^{2ix} + 6 + 4e^{-2ix} + e^{-4ix}}{16}\\
\frac {e^{4ix}+ e^{-4ix} + 4e^{2ix}+ 4e^{-2ix} + 6}{16}\\
\frac {\frac {e^{4ix}+ e^{-4ix}}{2} + 4\frac {e^{2ix}+ e^{-2ix}}{2} + 3}{8}\\
\frac {\cos 4x + 4\cos 2x + 3}{8}$
More Alternatives
$\cos 4x = 8\cos^4 x - 8\cos^2x + 1\\
\cos^2 x = \frac 12(\cos 2x + 1)\\
\cos 4x = 8\cos^4 x - 4\cos 2x  - 3\\
8\cos^4 x = \cos 4x + 4\cos 2x + 3\\
\cos^4 x = \frac 18 \cos 4x + \frac 12\cos 2x + \frac 38$

That matrix approach is quite interesting indeed... I am now wondering what other situations it may be useful for...

@RedFive One thought is that it suggests a transformation to a different basis for the set of periodic functions and there may be application to Fourier analysis.  I haven't investigated it though.

Might be a whole new discussion topic in it if/when you do...

If $$\cos^4(x)=A+B\cos(2x)+C\cos(4x)$$ is an identity, it must be true for small values of $x$. So, using Taylor
$$1-2 x^2+\frac{5 x^4}{3}+O\left(x^6\right)=(A+B+C)-2 (B+4 C)x^2+\frac{2}{3}  (B+16 C)x^4+O\left(x^6\right)$$
Just compare the coefficients.
